# Cube is black. How to make it green?

Tags: materials, color

[image][image]

I am trying to make this cube green. I tried to follow the tutorial but even after changing the base color the cube is still black. What do I need to do to make the cube green?

edit: blend file
[image]

Comment: It looks like your light is not hitting the cube, so it is green, but it appears black because it is in an unlit region. You can grab and move the light on top of the object; or, it might be easier for the moment to click on the light, change it from Point to Sun, and rotate the Sun so it is illuminating the object (alternatively, add a new Sun light, and similarly rotate it).

Comment: no, that didn't work

Comment: Check that your graphics drivers are up to date.

Comment: Is your alpha set to zero? Can't see entire material properties.

Comment: @NeverConvex No, it's not the light. The _Material Preview_ should show it without the scene lights and even if it did because this option had been enabled, the world background would illuminate it. So apart from possible driver issues it would be interesting to see the full material properties. As Adam suggests, this looks like Alpha is set to 0 - with _Blend Mode_ set to _Opaque_, this shows as black in the viewport.

Comment: Ah, good point--hopefully that will fix it

Comment: @user162065 -- thanks for uploading your .blend file. I opened it; it looks like you're in Vertex Paint mode, so the model looks black because it is indicating the strength with which vertices have been painted (and they haven't been painted). To see the normal textured views (where the object is green), you just need to switch the object back to, e.g., Object Mode or Edit Mode (hot keys for how to change modes depend on your version of Blender and your Blender settings; I use Tab to switch modes, but I work in an old version of Blender primarily)

Comment: @NeverConvex _Vertex Paint_ doesn't show "strength" (I guess you mean weight), this is done in _Weight Paint_ mode and a weight of 0 is indicated in blue. _Vertex Paint_ shows colors, starts white without anything painted. _Texture Paint_ would start showing black if you have a new black texture to paint on. However, when I opened the file the object was green, not white or black and there is no texture in the material for painting, no _Color Attributes_ (which you get when you start _vertex Painting). So if it wasn't the alpha transparency it is a driver issue or will remain a mystery.

Comment: @NeverConvex By the way, the screenshots where the object is completely black clearly show that it's _Object Mode_, not _Vertex Paint_. And even a black texture in _Texture Paint_ mode would show shading and not be pitch black.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann -- fair corrections. Try opening it in an older version of Blender, though; the cube is black for me if I open it in 2.83.2, but returns to green if I switch to Edit Mode, and remains green if I switch back to Object Mode. If I open it in 3.20, the cube is always green

Comment: Also--it appears to open in Object mode when I open it this morning as well (in both 2.83.2 and 3.20). Not sure why I saw Vertex Paint yesterday

Answer (score 1):

Check your *Alpha* value in the *Principled BSDF* shader, it is not visible in the screenshot. If it is set to 0, it will show as black in the *Material Preview* because by default it doesn't show alpha transparency. A value of 0 will show as black, any other value above 0 will show it as opaque green.

[image: alpha 0 opaque]

To get the alpha transparency to work you have to go into *Viewport Display* > *Settings* of the *Material Properties*. There you can set a different *Blend Mode* than the default *Opaque*, for example *Alpha Hashed* or *Alpha Blend*. With an alpha value of 0 the cube will now be completely invisible, higher values make it semi-transparent green. But note that alpha transparency is no proper use to create a transmissive material like glass for example.

[image: alpha 0 transparent]

[image: alpha > 0 semi-transparent]

Comment: Alpha is set to one, blend mode set to opaque

Comment: Maybe you could upload a copy of your .blend file, @user162065? If others can't replicate the problem, that would suggest an issue outside of Blender itself, e.g. graphics card or drivers

Comment: @user162065 That the blend mode is opaque was what I expected, it would be the reason for the black color if _Alpha_ was 0. But if it's 1 then we really might need your file to check what else is wrong.

Comment: added file upload to the initial question, hope that helps

Comment: @user162065 Sorry, I had no time to investigate the file earlier. On my computer the object is green, the vertex paint things NeverConvex mentions in the comments under the question cannot be the reason. So maybe it is a driver issue? Have you tried to start a new file with a new object and material? By the way, the cube has strange shading because you set it to shade smooth, but you should either shade it auto smooth or flat. And if you ever want to render it, the Sun lamp with a strength 10000 is overkill - and the light doesn't show in _Material Preview_ anyway if you thought it's too dark.